# How to check if number input has changed in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I got this form, and i have to set true/false value in controller based on changes in my inputs.
So it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.basicInfoForm.feed_intake.$invalid && (vm.basicInfoForm.feed_intake.$dirty || vm.basicInfoForm.$submitted)}">
  <label for="feed_intake">
  <data-i18n i18n="_m_f_pen_feed_intake_">feed intake</data-i18n>
  </label>
  <div>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="feed_intake" name="feed_intake" placeholder="{{'_m_f_pen_feed_intake_' | i18n}}&nbsp;({{vm.weight}}&nbsp;DM/day)" ng-model="vm.pen.feed_intake" required></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

So i need just small function in controller which will show me if anything has changed in my form. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use ng-change on input and when something changes you can set a boolean to true in order to save only changes

Comment: Could you please provide me some example?

Comment: see this my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/on2x8aL5/

Comment: Another option is to use `$scope.$watch` on `vm.pen.feed_intake` value. This can help  [Understanding How To Use $scope.$watch()](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm)